# Singular or plural "set"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I'm having some issues with a sentence that is part of the purpose in a report that I'm writing. I'm not sure if the word "communicate" (in bold) should be singular or plural.

The applications in the "set" will communicate with each other, not with other "sets".

> The purpose of this report is to develop a sample set of applications
>   that **communicates** between services on the internet, mobile devices
>   and a central processing unit in a motor vehicle.

Comment: Use the plural form (**communicate**) if you mean the "applications in the "set" will communicate with each other".

Comment: can communicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does "a \[x\] of \[y\]" take a singular or plural verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/does-a-x-of-y-take-a-singular-or-plural-verb) or [Is "a wide range of features" singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19399),  and also see [Which is correct: "one or more is" or "one or more are"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13284),

Comment: If the _applications_ each communicate, then plural. If the applications each contain only a simple function, so that several of them are required to complete a communication (e.g. set up a session, send a message, close the session), then it's the _set_ that's communicating, so singular.

Answer (score 1):

You have a set (of applications that communicate) not a set (of applications) that communicates, right?

Comment: Actually the applications communicate(s?) between themselves. So I guess it should be communicates?

Comment: @span okay, I'll bite: what's with the S in parentheses? If "the applications communicates" is even an option for you, you should be posting on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) instead. Also, if the applications actually communicate between themselves, you'll probably have to rewrite your original sentence to include that.

Comment: @span, the point is that the applications communicate, not the set.

Comment: Ok, thank you friends. I rewrote my sentence. Thank you for your efforts. Sorry I can't accept this as a correct answer as it seems to me that RegDwighт has a strong point.