# Use of “What kind”, and “What kind” vs “Which kind”

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, which-what

If we want to know the exact kind of a group of brids, should we say:

> A: "What is the kind of these birds?"

or

> B: "What kind of birds are these birds"?

If the questions above are phrased correctly, then there is a new question raised. Suppose there are three kinds of birds: A, B, and C, and the kind C is facing extinction. If we want to know the name of the kind that is facing extinction, how should we ask:

> A: What kind of birds *is* facing extinction?

or

> B: What kind of birds *are* facing extinction?

or

> C: *Which* kind of birds is facing extinction?

Which one is correct?

Comment: This is several unrelated questions in one, at least two of them duplicates of existing questions. See [“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot) and [Can “what kind” be plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43933/can-what-kind-be-plural)

Answer (score 1):

> - What kind of bird is this?
> - What kind of birds are these? <sup>[EDIT]</sup>
> - What kind of bird are these? (for a flock of identical birds) <sup>[EDIT]</sup>
> - What kinds of birds are these? (assumes two or more different types of birds)
> - What kinds of birds are facing extinction? (assumes two or more different types of birds)
> - Which kind of bird is facing extinction? (assumes the three birds in the question, not the entire spectrum of bird species) <sup>[EDIT]</sup>
> - Which of these three kinds of birds is facing extinction? (same as above) <sup>[EDIT]</sup>
> - Which kinds of birds are facing extinction? (assumes a limited choice, say, 25 on a page, not the entire spectrum of bird species) <sup>[EDIT]</sup>

[Thanks to J.R., StoneyB, and Andrew Leach for the information in the EDITs].

Comment: All those, plus, _Which kind of bird is facing extinction?_ (assumes two or more kinds of birds, presumably only one of which is facing extinction)

Comment: _Which_ is correct if we have a limited choice, say, for example, a page with pictures of 25 different species. If there's no context, then _what_ is correct because there are too many species to choose from.

Comment: @StoneyB: I just edited the answer to question.

Comment: Lends real substance to "The Reader Over Your Shoulder" doesn't it! ... I'm deleting my comments.

Comment: And *What kind of bird are these?* (for a flock of identical birds)

Comment: @Andrew: Good one! I'll add this to my answer. Thank you.