# Should the singular or plural be used in 'capstans are not the only product(s)...'?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Capstans are not the only product(s) we manufacture.

Should 'product' be singular or plural in this sentence?

Context: This particular company makes capstans in various shapes and sizes. I guess it all depends on whether we consider 'capstans' to be a product group?

Comment: This question is more interesting, and more complex, than  it may initially appear. It deserves a good answer if no good duplicate can be found.

Comment: Apparently someone thinks the answer is obvious, and that you should just have looked it up. Me, I have no idea whether or why anyone might assume that either "plurality" is definitely "right" or "wrong". To *my* native speaker's ear, both versions are fine, but whether or why I might choose to use either myself isn't something I could instantly articulate and/or justify. (***Snap!*** - you owe me a coke, @tchrist! :)

Comment: (Or I owe you a coke. I still don't really "get" that AmE usage.)

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know if the brand still exists, but I'm inclined to think exactly the same issue could be illustrated by a tobacconist saying ***[Players'] Capstans are not the only cigarette/s we sell.*** Albeit so far as I know there is/was only one version of those (*untipped* cigarettes), whereas obviously a manufacturer of "pulley components" could make them in a huge variety of shapes and sizes.

Comment: I guess it’s a quirk of grammar that “they are not the only thing(s) we make” is idiomatic either way.

Comment: You should include that info in your Question text itself. Hopefully these comments won't get deleted too soon (after all, tchrist is a mod himself), but I certainly can't give you an answer - in comments or as a formal "Answer" post below.

Comment: This *might* be a duplicate (or at least "related to") earlier [“One of the children who was” vs. “one of the children who were”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185714/one-of-the-children-who-was-vs-one-of-the-children-who-were), but personally I'm not willing to go so far as to closevote citing that one.

Comment: MKas - Congratulations on an edit well made! (I'm only sorry I can't give you a *second* upvote for the question!) As a minor point, we don't generally want to encourage adding "anticipatory thanks" to a question (if not yourself, someone else with extensive "edit" privileges might eventually delete that bit). But I certainly think the question is well presented and inherently interesting, even to people who think they know English very well indeed. Keep 'em coming!

Comment: The specific question aside (unless diversion is acceptable), I would rephrase it to: *We make more than just capstans.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Look for some kind of "these kind of things" duplicate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Related: [Can “what kind” be plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43933)

Comment: @tchrist♦: Are you trying to "nudge" me into casting a dup vtc? I see your "related" question has 5 votes, but [*Types of things vs. types of thing*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/) has 32, and looks like much the same kind/type of thing to me, so shouldn't that be the front runner? I don't know if it's relevant that I can more or less accept OP's *specific* noun ***product*** as a sort of "mass/uncountable" noun (as in *The product of bees includes both honey and beeswax*). But I can't see that line of reasoning working with my ***cigarette/s*** example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’ve not paid it sufficient thought yet to make that recommendation. I just remembered that this was related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is fine because *product* can serve as a count noun or mass noun, and the subject complement construction allows for either form.

The structure we're dealing with is:

> 

A are not the only B ...

A is a plural noun. B is a noun that denotes what kind of thing A is. This is a recurring structure in English, with 842 results in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) to work with. So my answer to this question may also explain some portion of the sample that use singular B with plural A. (A quick count suggests that out of the first 100 entries, 38 have singular B and 62 have plural B, so B is singular at least sometimes.)

Why, then, would **product** (or a similar noun) be valid in singular or plural form?

In this structure, *B* is a subject complement to *A* as connected by a linking verb, modified by an adjective (only, which customarily takes an article *the*, a possessive pronoun, or a possessive noun in this usage [according to the Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131462)), which is in turn modified by a negating adverb (not).

In simple examples of the subject complement found in grammar guides, when it is a noun, the number of the subject complement corresponds to the number of the subject:

> [Brandon is a gifted athlete](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm). (Singular -> Singular)

> [He became a famous writer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/subject-complements). (Singular -> Singular)

> [Both the brothers became doctors](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/complements). (Plural -> Plural)

That's often true when we're dealing with count nouns, or nouns which describe a countable quantity of something. However, some nouns act as [noncount nouns or mass nouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns), which cannot be counted. A mass noun does not take a plural form, so when it serves as the subject complement of a plural subject, it remains unchanged:

> Bananas and apples are [fruit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fruit)

> Puppies are [happiness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/happiness). (Seen in the wild in [this product description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075XR5H45).)

Some mass nouns are always mass nouns. Other mass nouns are sometimes mass nouns and sometimes count nouns, or they can be converted into a count noun through usage (will you order me coffee? -> I'll have two coffees). If you read *fruit* and thought that making it plural would be acceptable as well, you're right, because *fruit* also sometimes works as a count noun to describe *pieces of fruit* or *kinds of fruit*:

> Bananas and apples are fruits.

Mass nouns also sometimes convert to count nouns. In the article "[The Lexical Semantics of English Count and Mass Nouns](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0952-1_2)" (1999) author Brendan S. Gillon states four denotations (meanings) when mass nouns are converted to count noun:

1. To be a kind of
2. To be an instance of
3. to be a unit of
4. To be a source of

In mass form, this is often their purpose anyway, but as count nouns they can now indicate a countable kind of/instance of/unit of/source of something. So when I say "Puppies are happiness," I'm saying puppies are an instance or source of happiness. When I say "Bananas and apples are fruit," I'm saying that bananas and apples are kinds of fruit. When *fruit* is converted to a count noun, "Bananas and apples are fruits" suggests that they are kinds of fruits *and also* that they are countable instances of this. The subject complement allows for this kind of flexibility between count and mass nouns.

So, back to *product* and *products*, either one is acceptable because *[product](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/product)* can operate as both a mass noun and a count noun in a similar way to *fruit*. As a mass noun, *product* describes the kind of thing capstans are: they are a kind of product, and "we" produce other kinds of product. As a count noun, *products* corresponds with *capstans* because (in mass noun form) capstans are a kind of product, and (now in count noun form) capstans are (countable) products. The end result is a lot of nuance between two example sentences understood in similar ways by fluent readers:

> Capstans are not the only product we manufacture.

> Capstans are not the only products we manufacture.