# Subject in the sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, subjects

> The most common *kind* **is** the curves.
>
> The *data* **is** pairs of y and x.

Are subjects of these sentences *kind* and *data*, which means that **is** is the predicator (not are), right? I am confused by the following plural (but these are objects, right?). Thank you

Comment: For the first sentence, the subject is the noun phrase _The most common kind_; for the second, _it's the noun phrase _The data._ Predicate in both sentences is the remaining part. _Data_, by the way, is pluralized.

Comment: Thank you, but my teacher says that data is singular.

Comment: Sorry, your teacher is right. It is a plural noun that can take a singular or plural verb.

Comment: This is an ELL question, and isn't really suited for this forum. https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "data" treated as singular or plural in formal contexts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/is-data-treated-as-singular-or-plural-in-formal-contexts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement in "\[Singular Noun\] Is/Are \[Plural Noun\]"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun)

Comment: Your teacher is right: with "data", singular construal is standard. Note, though, that the singular predicand “is” does not match the plural predicatives “the curves” and “pairs of y and z”. However, mismatches of number do occur, especially with ascriptive “be”, and in your examples the mismatches seem acceptable. There are no objects: "the curves" and "pairs of y and x" are predicative complements of "be".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject/Complement Agreement. How to describe problem with "The thing is the objects."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj) (Better title, but  niamulbengali's duplicate outranks.)

Comment: See also [Can 'what kind of' be plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43933/can-what-kind-be-plural) ... What kind of ships travel under the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the question is closed (it is a duplicate of [Is "data" treated as singular or plural in formal contexts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/is-data-treated-as-singular-or-plural-in-formal-contexts)), consider this:

Data singular or plural is now a matter of choice.

*Data* is the Latin plural of *datum*, so your teacher is fundamentally wrong.

However, usage has shifted because of general ignorance of Latin, to use *data* as singular.

> Data - Usage: In Latin, data is the plural of datum and, historically and in specialized scientific fields, it is also treated as a plural in English, taking a plural verb, as in the data were collected and classified. In modern non-scientific use, however, it is generally not treated as a plural. Instead, it is treated as a mass noun, similar to a word like information, which takes a singular verb. Sentences such as data was collected over a number of years are now widely accepted in standard English
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/data)

We have to move with linguistic shift, so *data* is now often used as singular; in that sense your teacher is correct.

The important thing is to use one or the other consistently in whatever is written. Mixing them in the same prose is a mark of poor style and sloppy thinking.

Comment: I assume that despite my introductory remark, someone downvoted this because I answered a question very similar to an earlier one; I expected that and the matter deserves no further attention. If on the other hand the reason for the downvote is to do with the substance of the answer rather than the formalities of the site, perhaps the downvoter would explain to the PO why the answer is erroneous?